# No links will change mouse cursor to pointer when hovered

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

None of my links or images will change my mouse cursor to a pointer when hovered.

Even if they have a a tag and if they have a href. Even if I do

```
link{
cursor: pointer
}
```

or

```
link:hover{
cursor: pointer
}
```

Here are two examples of what i have:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/cneistat" id="facebook"> <img src="Images/facebook-btn.png"> </a>
```

and

```
<li data-controls="one"><a id="togglediv1" class="active-start">Vlogging</a></li>
```

The first one is a facbook icon that should be clickable. and the second is just a some text on the page that should be clickable as well. Granted they both work but when hovered over neither will change the cursor to a pointer. Right when you hover over it itll change to a pointer for a split second, but then itll just stay as your normal cursor.

And adding cursor:pointer to the CSS doesnt work either.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What pointer do you want, because pointer is the default for links...

Comment: Why does it say `link` in the CSS?

Comment: Your css is wrong you need to put .link{} and then you have to add link class to a or img. Please put together feedle example and I can show you further.

Comment: I know its suppose to be default for links but its not working. and 'link' in the css is just a placeholder to show you guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
Have a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j4k5qywm/2/

Let me know if you have any questions. It will be easier next time if   
you post a jsfiddle so that we can see the code that you have written.
Need to see how to post a fiddle not getting an error needs to 
be in a code block :-)
```